# Extracting a value from a HashMap with a dynamic key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Java Web Application with a `HashMap class` to store around 20 different web sites where the key is a specific code:

e.g code: AB  website: http://www.somewebsiteforAB.com

I generate the code (`HashMap key`) via another `Java Class` which is surfaced in the JSP for user display.

I am trying to understand how I can pass this 'dynamic' variable from the JSP to the HashMap to return the associated value.

My `Java class` is:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class FaMap {

    // Initialisers a static, immutable map containing relevant web sites

    private static final Map<String, String> fMap;

    static {

       /* Declaring the HashMap*/
        Map<String, String> aMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

       /* Adding elements to HashMap*/
        aMap.put("AB", "https://www.somewebsiteforAB.com/");
        aMap.put("CD", "https://www.somewebsiteforCD.com/");
        aMap.put("EF", "https://www.somewebsiteforEF.com/");
        aMap.put("GH", "https://www.somewebsiteforGH.com/");

        fMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(aMap);        

       /* Display content using Iterator*/
        Set<Entry<String, String>> set = fMap.entrySet();
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = set.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, String> mentry = iterator.next();
        }
    }
}
```

The above class will print the keys and values for all or any specified key using System.out.println statements within the class. But how do I pass the map a dynamically generated key to extract the relevant value and pass this back to the JSP.

Do I need to write another method that accepts the key as an parameter and passes this to the map?

Comment: Iterate the map and find the value according the key?

Comment: What is it with your JSP? What is a _dynamic variable_? Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can just create a new method that will receive the key that is being displayed in your JSP.

Something like this:

```
public String getValueWithKey(String keyFromJSP) {
    return fMap.get(keyFromJSP);
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for clarifying my thinking.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your dynamic var needs to be created. for example:

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="AB"/>
```

Once you have this, and have an instance of your map (let's call it fMap) you can simply call it like in Java. for example:

```
<c:set var="myWebsite" value="${fMap.get(myVar)}"/>
```

And you also need a pulbic Java method that will allow you access to the map. for example:

```
public Map<String, String> getMap() {
    return fMap;
}
```